# invalidHandler fires multiple times

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validator plug-in to validate a simple Contact Request form. The requirements are:

1. Validation occurs on form submission as well as onfocusout.
2. Text messages are placed in the title of the field for hover. This part is omitted here because it's not part of the problem.
3. Upon form submission if any errors are found, a dialog box appears stating the number of errors found with instructions to return to the form.

The problem I am running into is with the invalidHandler event of the validate. If I load the form and then click Submit I get the dialog as expected. It is when I set a breakpoint or a simple alert within the function that I learn that it fires 3 times.

Additionally I was under the impression the invalidHandler event only fires upon form submission. If I enter a field and then leave it blank, the onfocusout fires as expected but then the invalidHander fires again, bringing up the dialog. I removed the onfocusout event from the validate, but it still fires every time.

Side note: on the extra calls to the event, as well as the unexpected ones, the formatting in the dialog is way off, the entire interior script is about 10px wide.

I've searched and tried about all I can think of. The code is below, any ideas where I am tripping up? Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
                <form id="kontaktform" name="kontaktform" method="post" action="">
                    <p>
                        <input type="radio" name="rblType" id="rb_0 tabindex="1" value="1" /> Item 1<br />
                        <input type="radio" name="rblType" id="rb_1 tabindex="2" value="2" /> Item 2<br />
                        <input type="radio" name="rblType" id="rb_2 tabindex="3" value="3"/> Item 3<br />                       </p>
                    <fieldset id="fs_pers">
                        <legend>Pers&#246;nliche Informationen</legend>
                        <div>
                            <label for="txtVorname">Vor-/Nachname:</label>
                            <select name="ddlSal" id="ddl_sal">
                                <option value="1">Herr</option>
                                <option value="2">Frau</option>
                            </select>&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" name="txtFName" id="txtFName" maxlength="50" tabindex="6" />&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" name="txtLName" id="txtLName" maxlength="50" tabindex="7" /><span class="req">*</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="txtFirma" id="lbl_firma" class="lblDisabled">Firma</label>
                            <input type="text" name="txtFirm" id="txtFirm" maxlength="50" tabindex="8" style="width: 450px;" class="txtDisabled disabled="disabled" /><span id="req_firm" class="req hide">*</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="txtAdresse">Adresse:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="txtAddr" id="txtAddr" maxlength="100" tabindex="9" style="width: 450px;" /><span class="req">*</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="txtPLZ">PLZ/Ort:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="txtPostal" id="txtPostal" class="plz" maxlength="10" tabindex="10" style="width: 60px" />&nbsp;
                            <input type="text" name="txtCity" id="txtCity" maxlength="50" tabindex="11" style="width: 380px;" /><span class="req">*</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="txtTele">Telefon:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="txtTele" id="txtTele" maxlength="50" tabindex="12" class="contactinfo defaultText" style="width: 450px;" /><span class="req">*</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="txtEmail">E-Mail:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="txtEmail" id="txtEmail" maxlength="75" tabindex="13" class="contactinfo defaultText" style="width: 450px;" /><span class="req">*</span>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset id="fs_question">
                        <legend>Nachrichten<span class="req">*</span></legend>
                        <div>
                            <textarea name="txtComments" id="txtComments" tabindex="14></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="buttonDiv">
                        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" tabindex="16" id="btnSubmit" value="Senden..." />
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div id="diverror" style="display: none" title="Fehler Gefunden">
                    <p id="divmsg"></p>
                </div>
```

Here is the specific validation jQuery info:

```
var rqTxt = {
    required: true,
    minlength: 1
}
$('#kontaktform').validate({
    debug: true,
    onfocusout: function (element) {
        $(element).valid();
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        return true;
    },
    errorClass: 'error',
    rules: {
        txtFName: rqTxt,
        txtLName: rqTxt,
        txtComments: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 1000
        },
        txtTele: {
            require_from_group: [1, ".contactinfo"]
        },
        txtEmail: {
            email: true,
            require_from_group: [1, ".contactinfo"]
        }
    },
    invalidHandler: function (form, validator) {
        var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
        if (errors) {
            $('#divmsg').html('Sie haben {0} Fehler in Ihrer Kontaktanfrage. Bitte &#252;berpr&#252;fen Sie die Formulare und versuchen Sie, Ihre Anfrage erneut zu senden.'.replace('{0}', errors));
            $('#diverror').dialog({
                dialogClass: 'diverror',
                modal: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: "Schließen",
                    "class": "btnClass",
                    click: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }]
            });
            $('#diverror').dialog('option', 'title', errors + ' Fehler Gefunden');
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        if ($(form).valid() && confirm('Sind Sie sicher?')) {
            form.submit();
            return false;
        }
    }

});
```

(Moving my "answer" to an actual answer for this question as my 24 hour wait period is up.)

Comment: the 3 `<input>`s at the start of your HTML are invalid, you need to close the quotes on the `id=` attribute!

Comment: Here's what you **don't** need to be doing: 1) You don't need to declare `onfocuout` with a function when that's already the default behavior. 2) If you want to suppress default error messages, then put `return false`, not `true`, inside the `errorPlacement` callback.  3)  You don't need to test if the form is valid from inside the `submitHandler` since it only fires on a valid form in the first place.  4)  Likewise, you don't need to test for errors within `invalidHandler` since it will not fire when there are no errors.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. The missing quotes are my fault, I pulled some extra php coding out of the sample and the quote disappeared with it. @sparky, thanks for the tips. They actually tightened up the problem and now I don't get the repeats, except for when I am using the require_from_group. Both of those still activate the invalidHandler. The require_from_group is a serious problem for me, in its original form it is bugged so that if any fields proceed it they won't be validated. I updated my additional-methods.js with the fix posted here and at the site, but now I have this problem.

Comment: Instead of "fixing" `additional-methods.js`, use the latest version which took care of all the bugs.  Use version 1.11.1 of both plugin files.

Comment: That's the version I am using. Until I installed the fix presented on the validator website and here, the require_from_group worked but any fields before it in the form that were to be validated would not get included in the validation. (here is the link...https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/412

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to the tips from Sparky, along with looking a bit deeper into the fix posted in Github for the require_from_group bug after Sparky commented on 1.11.1 I found the answer.

First was that I had the validator set up wrong (big thing was the errorPlacement callback.

Second and what seemed to be compounding the problem was the require_from_group bug. I had originally updated the additional-methods.js file as recommended by the issue tracker for issue 412 (see above comment for link) but that was still causing the dialog to appear if I focused either of the grouped fields and then blurred it by moving to another field or removing focus from the page.

Then I revisited the page and found the following:

[Fix require_from_group and skip_or_fill_minimum - e5207d6](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/commit/e5207d63a831fdfa30ea6927906288ae60336c76)

The fix is there, I clipped it and updated the additional-methods.js file with the new code and now it works as expected.

Thanks for the tips!